# bash, list filenames, array

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, filenames

I have a dir structure like

```
$ ls /comp/drive/
2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014

$ ls 2009
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  09  10  11  12

$ ls 2013
01  02  04  05  06  08  09  10  12

$ ls 2013/04/*.nc
file4.nc file44.nc file45.nc file49.nc
```

There are dirs like years and each year there are few months dirs and inside are .nc files.

What I want to do is get the array of filenames provided start and end years/months.

e.g. `sYear=2011; eYear=2013; sMonth=03; eMonth=08`

So, I want to get the array of all filenames from year 2011/03 to 2013/08 only without going inside  the dirs.

Any bash trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sYear=2011
sMonth=03

eYear=2013
eMonth=08

shopt -s nullglob
declare -a files

for year in *; do
    (( ${year} < ${sYear} || ${year} > ${eYear} )) && continue

    for year_month in ${year}/*; do

        month=${year_month##*/}
        (( ${year} == ${sYear} && ${month##0} < ${sMonth##0} )) && continue;
        (( ${year} == ${eYear} && ${month##0} > ${eMonth##0} )) && continue;

        files+=(${year_month}/*.nc)
    done
done

echo "${files[@]}"
# printf "$(pwd)/%q\n" "${files[@]}" # for full path
```

Comment: First -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Second, `08` is treated as *octal*, not *decimal*, so this is buggy as-given with months numbered above 7 but below 10. Third, use of unquoted `${files[*]}` is almost always the Wrong Thing -- if you had filenames with spaces, they'd be broken out into separate arguments, if you had a file with an `*` in its name surrounded by spaces, that glob would actually be expanded. Quoted `"${files[@]}"` is the Right Thing.

Comment: Not quite right here either -- the glob expression can't be in the quotes, even though the expansions should be. You want `files+=( "${year}/${month}/"*.nc )`, or somesuch. (The curly braces are strictly optional in this context).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I just threw a quick example. Didn't actually test it. Thanks for catching the errors -- I fixed them.

Comment: *nod*. I think you posted your answer about 6 seconds before mine, and they certainly have a lot in common. Parallel development is funny like that.

Comment: The only remaining place where I see a bug is that the `month` variable will contain content like `2014/01`, not just `01`, but you're doing math on it that would expect the latter. Otherwise, this looks about perfect now.

Comment: Charles, you've got eagle eye :). OP should just accept your answer, since mine was full of bugs. If he doesn't I will upvote yours :)

Comment: It works well too. Thanks IB.

It would be nice to have the full path of filenames in the array.

Comment: @user3652962, I tweaked it to return paths relative to the current directory. If you want the full path, uncomment the last line with `printf`

Comment: @InnocentBystander, one last minor tweak -- it would be slightly more efficient (no subshell and thus fork/read/wait cycle) to use `$PWD` rather than `$(pwd)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sYear=2011; eYear=2013; sMonth=03; eMonth=08

# prevent bugs from interpreting numbers as hex
sMonth=$(( 10#$sMonth ))
eMonth=$(( 10#$eMonth ))

files=( )
for (( curYear=sYear; curYear <= eYear; curYear++ )); do
  # include only months after sMonth
  for monthDir in "$curYear"/*/; do
    [[ -e $monthDir ]] || continue # ignore years that don't exist
    curMonth=${monthDir##*/}
    (( curMonth )) || continue     # ignore non-numeric directory names
    (( curYear == sYear )) && (( 10#$curMonth < sMonth )) && continue
    (( curYear == eYear )) && (( 10#$curMonth > eMonth )) && continue
    files+=( "$monthDir"/*.nc )
  done
done

printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, 
I get this

`sMonth=(( 10#sMonth ))`
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Also, it would be better to have the full paths of the filenames in the final ${files[@]}. Sorry to bother again.

Comment: Needs to be `sMonth=$((10#sMonth))` or `((sMonth = 10#sMonth))`. Will answer more completely when at a real console.

Comment: @user3652962, by "full" paths do you mean absolute? The only change necessary for that is to change `"$curYear"/*/` to `"$PWD/$curYear"/*/`.